# Network Analysis: Finding fastest route through an area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I'm working on a project where drivers have to remove snow from the sidewalk of streets.

the drivers will start at the facility go through a certain neighborhood(area) of streets and return to the same facility. My question is there a way to find the fastest route through that area and just return to the facility.

My question does sound similar to other questions posted as I have read questions that sound close to mines, but based on the wording I am not if it fully answers my question. At the moment I am not near the ArcGIS software to test some of the responses.

If anyone has any answers or can point me in the right direction that would be helpful.

Comment: Related/duplicates: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99886/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66373/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101511/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Route analysis solver should be able to take care of this for you. Just include stops in the analysis and the solver can plot the best route (or whatever criteria you specify) through locations you need to cover.

[Network Analyst - Route analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/extensions/network-analyst/route.htm)